# How does a neutron star emitting magnetic-dipole radiation lose angular momentum?

Tags: neutron-star

Is the ultimate reason that the neutron star loses angular momentum that the [magnetic-dipole radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) is not spherically symmetric and photons have momentum?

Just for the loss of angular momentum, particles emitted from the neutron star surface are not necessary, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't made the connection to astronomy clear. Better on Physics.

Answer (score 9):

Radiation carries a momentum *per unit volume* given by
$$ \vec{p} = \epsilon_0 \vec{E} \times \vec{B}$$

It therefore carries an angular momentum of
$$ \vec{L} = \vec{r}\times \vec{p} = \epsilon_0 \vec{r} \times (\vec{E}\times \vec{B})$$

For plane-polarised transverse electromagnetic waves propagating in the $\hat{r}$ direction, then $\vec{L}=0$. However, if the axis of a magnetic dipole is inclined to the rotation axis then the radiation is not a single pure transverse wave; the dipole moment is the sum of two oscillating magnetic dipole moments that are perpendicular and oscillate $\pi/2$ out of phase. These produce two transverse waves, with arbitrary amplitudes, perpendicular polarisations and a $\pi/2$ phase shift between them - a.k.a. [elliptically polarised light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_polarization). Elliptically polarised light carries [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light).

Comment: Magnetic-dipole radiation is not spherically symmetric, then a neutron star can decelerate. But the main reason is elliptically polarised light carries angular momentum?

Comment: Indeed dipolar fields are not spherically symmetric but that does not necessarily carry away angular momentum. The elliptical polarisation induced by a rotating dipole moment is I think crucial.

Comment: I am not sure if you are right...

Comment: About what @questionhang ?

Comment: I am not sure the elliptical polarization is the main reason.